# Randomize Wordpress Publish Time Or Random Posts Once A Day

Tags: wordpress, posts

i really did my searching homework on this but i still dont have a solution.

I have a video tube site based on wordpress engine, it shows 12 vid thumbnails(posts)/page.
But it appears in publish time order(as usual for wordpress) but in this site it is not so good. I would like the posts to be randomized(shuffle post date) once a day.

i can integrate the

query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand');

but thats a half the solution because this randomizes the post on every page load and on every page, so there is a chance that the same vid appears on page1 and 2.

So i need a solution that randomizes the posts on the whole site at once, and once a day.

The best way would be somehow to shuffle the post dates of the publishig time of each post.

I cant believe there is no plugin for this:)
Thanks in forwards.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a little script that randomize post dates.

```
$date_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date1       = date( $date_format, strtotime("-1 year", time()) );
$date2       = date( $date_format, time() );
$post_type   = 'post'; // post, page, product or some other custom post type

// Get all the posts
$posts = get_posts( array( 
        'numberposts' => -1, // get ALL posts
        'post_status' => 'any', // published, pending, draft, future, trash
        'post_type'   => $post_type 
  ));

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

  //* Generate a random post dates
  $random_date = mt_rand( strtotime( $date1 ), strtotime($date2) );

  //* Format the date that WordPress likes
  $post_date = date( $date_format, $random_date );

  // We only want to update the post date
  $update = array(
        'ID'            => $post->ID,
        'post_date'     => $post_date,
        'post_date_gmt' => null,
  );

  //* Update the post
  wp_update_post( $update );

}
```

Aldo this thread is pretty old, I hope this will help someone looking for this answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're assuming that your query is randomized, Wordpress can't avoid show the same content in different pages.

Comment: Yes i know, that is why the so called(i named it:) post date shuffler would be a good technique, a script that changes the publish date of each post to a relative random date so the posts would be mixed each time it runs trough